# Print and Email document created on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, printing, document

I need to modify an app to print and email a document created on the iPad.

I'm thinking that I should create a PDF document, as shown in the tutorial link below:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2

However, once created, I want to print and/or email the document? Are there any other suggestions which may not require pdf document?

I need to create a document based on data entered into a UIView and then either print and/or email it accordingly.

Any suggestions or assistance with this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `UIDocumentInteractionController` for this purpose. Once you've created your PDF, you can present it with `UIDocumentInteractionController` by passing the URL of your created/saved PDF. This automatically gives you the option of printing/copying and emailing.

**Example:** (Assuming that you've saved your PDF in the local Documents folder)

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SAVED_PDF_NAME HERE"];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:writableDBPath];
    if (URL) {
        // Initialize Document Interaction Controller
        documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];
    documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.adobe.pdf";
    // Configure Document Interaction Controller
    [documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];
    [documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES]; // This will present the PDF along with options like Mail, Print and Copy..
```

**NOTE:** This is after creating your PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll look into this and will update this once done. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, in order for it to work though, I needed to add in the delegate method - (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPrevie…{    return [self navigationController];} but it works a treat and does exactly what I need done.

Comment: That's right. I am sorry, I've missed that.. I guess you'd have been prompted for that by XCode.. :D Glad that this helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following links

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/drawingprintingios.pdf 
or
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/Printing/Printing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH12-SW14

Comment: Thanks mate, however, I have already seen those links on apples website.